# PYSPARK - Solution for slow performance when writing dataframe to parquet file when using repartition() before partitionby()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partition

I want to write my data (contained in a dataframe) into parquet files.
I need to partition the data by two variables : "month" and "level". (data is always filtered on these 2 variables)

If I do the following 
`data.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("month", "level").save("...")` I end up with the expected partitions, however i have a lot of files per partitions. Some of these files are really small which hurt the performance of queries run on the data.

In order to correct that, I tried to apply `repartition` before writing the data :
`data.repartition("month", "level").write.format("parquet").partitionBy("month", "level").save("...")` which give me exactly what i want (1 file per partition, with a decent size for each file).

===> the problem here is that the repartition causes a full shuffle of the data, which means that for an input data of 400Gb, I end up with a few Tb of shuffle...

Is there any way to optimize the repartition() before the partitionby() or to do this any other way ?

Thanks !